# Permanently marking a table after finishing

Tags: woodworking, wooden-furniture

I just finished building a patio table that has a satin spar varnish finish. It turned out well but now my wife is asking if there is a way for my boys to permanently write their names or initials on it.  My first thought was woodburning but I am not sure that would work because of the varnish. [image]

Answer (score 1):

Nail polish. Waterproof, durable, comes in a wide variety of colors, and it already includes a small brush.

Answer (score 1):

A Sharpie will last a long time.  If you want it really permanent, have them write in Sharpie or even a dry erase marker, which would allow revision if they mess up.  Then go over it with a Dremel or engraving tool to carve it into the surface.  It doesn't need to go very deep.  You can then enhance it if you want by filling it with a dark filler stick.

Comment: Sharpie ink doesn't last that long. In a couple years, it'll be considerably faded.